# Can't figure out how to fix compiler errors. (Easy beginner program)

Tags: c, struct, compilation

I get the following errors when trying to compile in Codeblocks:

```
main.c|94|error: expected expression before '==' token|
main.c|99|error: expected expression before '==' token|
main.c|100|error: 'title' undeclared (first use in this function)|
main.c|100|note: each undeclared identifier is reported only once for each function it appears in|
main.c|119|error: incompatible types when assigning to type 'char[3]' from type 'char *'|
main.c|133|error: expected expression before '==' token|
main.c|138|error: expected expression before '==' token|
main.c|159|error: incompatible types when assigning to type 'char[3]' from type 'char *'|
main.c|188|error: expected expression before 'int'|
main.c|201|error: expected expression before '==' token|
main.c|206|error: expected expression before '==' token|
||=== Build failed: 10 error(s), 0 warning(s) (0 minute(s), 0 second(s)) ===|
```

Here is my code.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

#define LENGTH == 30;

typedef struct {
    char div[3];
    short dept, num;
    char credits[3];
    char title[30];
} course;

int main()
{
    printf("Welcome to the Ultimate Course Database App!\n");

    int input;
    char filenameOne[20];
    char filenameTwo[20];

    printf("Please type in the name of the database file:\n");
    scanf("%s", &filenameOne);

    FILE *in_file  = fopen(filenameOne, "r");

    //If the file does not exist
    if (!in_file)
    {
        printf("The file you entered does not exist. A new file with the same name will be created for you.\n");

        //Create the file
        FILE *in_file = fopen(filenameOne, "w");
        course Course;
        for (int counter=0; counter <= 559999; counter++)
        {
            Course.dept == 000;
            Course.num == 000;
            fwrite(&Course, sizeof(course), 1, in_file);
        }
    }

    do
    {
        fseek(in_file, 0, SEEK_SET);

        printf("Please choose from the options below, by typing in the corresponding number.\n");

        printf("1: Create new courses from a plain text file, adding them to the database.\n");
        printf("2: Add a single course to the database.\n");
        printf("3: Display all the details of a particular course.\n");
        printf("4: Display all the actual courses in the database.\n");
        printf("5: Change the name of a course in the database.\n");
        printf("6: Delete a course from the database.\n");
        printf("7: Add a course to a semester course listing.\n");
        printf("8: Remove a course from a semester course listing.\n");
        printf("9: Display a semester course listing, in course number order.\n");
        printf("10: Quit.\n");

        scanf("%d", &input);

        //If Option 1 is selected
        if (input == 1) {
            printf("You selected Option 1: Create new courses from a plain text file, adding them to the database.\n");
            printf("Please type in the name of your text file below.\n");
            scanf("%s", &filenameTwo);
            FILE *in_file_text  = fopen(filenameTwo, "r");
            if (!in_file_text) {
                fprintf(stderr, "File not found.\n");
            }
            while (feof(in_file_text)) {
                //Joanne's code
                int c1, c2;
                char div[3], title[LENGTH+1];
                int dept, num;
                int count = 0;
                int c = ' ';
                fscanf(in_file_text, "%2s.%d.%d %d.%d ", div, &dept, &num, &c1, &c2);
                while (count < LENGTH && (c = fgetc(in_file_text)) != '\n') {
                    title[count++] = (char) c;
                }
                title[count] = '\0';
                while (c != '\n') c = fgetc(in_file_text);

                //error checking
                if (!(dept<701 && dept>001 && num<899 && num>100 && (c1 == 0 || c1 == 1 || c1 == 5) && (c2 == 0 || c2 == 1 || c2 == 5))) {
                    fprintf(stderr, "Invalid input.\n");
                }

                course ToVerify;
                fseek(in_file, ((dept)*700)+(num-100), SEEK_SET);
                fread(&ToVerify, sizeof(course), 1, in_file);

                //check to see if empty course or not
                if (ToVerify.dept == 000 && ToVerify.num == 000) {
                    course ToAdd;
                    ToAdd.dept = dept;
                    ToAdd.num = num;
                    ToAdd.div = div;
                    ToAdd.title = title;
                    fwrite(&ToAdd, sizeof(course), 1, in_file);
                }
            }
            fclose(in_file_text);
        }

        //If option 2 is selected
        if (input == 2) {
            printf("You selected Option 2: Add a single course to the database.\n");
            printf("Please type in the course below.\n");
            //Joanne's code
            int c1, c2;
            char div[3], title[LENGTH+1];
            int dept, num;
            int count = 0;
            int c = ' ';
            fscanf(stdin, "%2s.%d.%d %d.%d ", div, &dept, &num, &c1, &c2);
            while (count < LENGTH && (c = fgetc(stdin)) != '\n') {
                title[count++] = (char) c;
            }
            title[count] = '\0';
            while (c != '\n') c = fgetc(stdin);

            //do the whole thing from 1 all over again
            //error checking
            if (!(dept<701 && dept>001 && num<899 && num>100 && (c1 == 0 || c1 == 1 || c1 == 5) && (c2 == 0 || c2 == 1 || c2 == 5))) {
                fprintf(stderr, "Invalid input.\n");
            }

            course ToVerify;
            fseek(in_file, ((dept)*700)+(num-100), SEEK_SET);
            fread(&ToVerify, sizeof(course), 1, in_file);

            //check to see if empty course or not
            if (ToVerify.dept == 000 && ToVerify.num == 000) {
                course ToAdd;
                ToAdd.dept = dept;
                ToAdd.num = num;
                ToAdd.div = div;
                ToAdd.title = title;
                fwrite(&ToAdd, sizeof(course), 1, in_file);
            }
        }

        //If option 3 is selected
        if (input == 3) {
            printf("You selected Option 3: Display all the details of a particular course.\n");
            printf("Please type in the department and course number below.\n");
            int dept, num;
            fscanf(stdin, "%d.%d", &dept, &num);

            // check for input error
            if (!(dept<701 && dept>001 && num<899 && num>100)) {
                fprintf(stderr, "Invalid input.\n");
            }
            course ToDisplay;
            fseek(in_file, ((dept)*700)+(num-100), SEEK_SET);
            fread(&ToDisplay, sizeof(course), 1, in_file);
            printf("%2s.%d.%d %d.%d ", ToDisplay.div, ToDisplay.dept, ToDisplay.num, ToDisplay.credits, ToDisplay.title);
        }

        //If Option 4 is selected
        if (input == 4) {
            printf("You selected Option 4: Display all courses.\n");
            while (int counter = 0, counter < 560000, counter++) {
                course ToDisplay;
                fread(&ToDisplay, sizeof(course), 1, in_file);
                if (ToDisplay.dept != 000 && ToDisplay.num != 000) {
                    printf("%2s.%d.%d %d.%d ", ToDisplay.div, ToDisplay.dept, ToDisplay.num, ToDisplay.credits, ToDisplay.title);
                }
            }
        }

        //If option 5 is selected
        if (input == 5) {
            printf("You selected Option 5: Change the name of a course.\n");
            printf("Please type in the department and course number below, with the new name\n");
            char title[LENGTH+1];
            int dept, num;
            int count = 0;
            int c = ' ';
            fscanf(stdin, "%2s.%d.%d", div, &dept, &num);
            while (count < LENGTH && (c = fgetc(fp)) != '\n') {
                title[count++] = (char) c;
            }
            title[count] = '\0';
            while (c != '\n') c = fgetc(stdin);

            //check for input error DO
            if (!(dept<701 && dept>001 && num<899 && num>100)) {
                fprintf(stderr, "Invalid input.\n");
            }

            course ToChange;
            fseek(in_file, ((dept)*700)+(num-100), SEEK_SET);
            fread(&ToChange, sizeof(course), 1, in_file);
            if (ToChange.dept != 000 && ToChange.num != 000) {
                ToChange.title = title;
                fwrite(&ToChange, sizeof(course), 1, in_file);
            }
            if (ToChange.dept == 000 && ToChange.num == 000) {
                fprintf(stderr, "Record id empty!");
            }
        }

        //If Option 6 is selected
        if (input == 6) {
            printf("You selected Option 6: Delete a course.\n");
            printf("Please type in the department and course number below.\n");
            int dept, num;
            fscanf(stdin, "%d.%d", &dept, &num);

            //check for input error DO
            if (!(dept<701 && dept>001 && num<899 && num>100)) {
                fprintf(stderr, "Invalid input.\n");
            }

            course ToDelete;
            fseek(in_file, ((dept)*700)+(num-100), SEEK_SET);
            fread(&ToDelete, sizeof(course), 1, in_file);
            if (ToDelete.dept != 000 && ToDelete.num != 000) {
                ToDelete.dept == 000;
                ToDelete.num == 000;
                ToDelete.div == "";
                ToDelete.credits == "";
                ToDelete.title == "";
                fwrite(&ToDelete, sizeof(course), 1, in_file);
            }
            if (ToDelete.dept == 000 && ToDelete.num == 000) {
                fprintf(stderr, "Record id empty!\n");
            }
        }
    }
    while (input < 10);
    fclose(in_file);
}
```

Comment: I'll get you started: `#define LENGTH 30`

Comment: Second prob: You need only single =

Comment: If you cant debug with all those compiler warnings, it means you havent written this code. I will suggest start learning the basics of the language first.

Comment: Fixed that. Thanks! Still have 10 errors. :(

Comment: I have indeed written the code myself (except for the part labelled "Joane's Code"), UnderDog - just short on time and need to fix these errors as soon as possible.

Comment: You need to **read the error messages** one by one, starting from the first one. Take a look at the line corresponding to each error in the file (sometimes the previous line/statement as well) and work out what's wrong with it.

Comment: I am voting to close this question down for the reason you are asking us to debug the code you have written "yourself" and the errors could be solved with the basic understanding of C.

Comment: @UnderDog agreed, OP did not write this code.

Comment: Don't really know how to convince you on this; all I can say is this is my code. The errors are pretty basic, but I'm having a hard time with them.

Comment: The clue is: you would not have got so far yet still have such basic errors. Nobody sits down and writes code of this extent without building and compiling step by step.

Comment: That's a mistake I made, then. Doesn't mean I didn't write the code myself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The define syntax is incorrect, the correct syntax is:

```
#define LENGTH 30
```

There is = and == mismatch here:

```
Course.dept = 000;
Course.num = 000;
```

Are you using C99? Unless it's the case, a declaration in the for loop is an error:

```
for (int counter=0; counter <= 559999; counter++)
```

Don't assign static char[X] with = here:

```
ToAdd.div = div;
ToAdd.title = title;
```

strcpy or strncpy must be used or directly write char into the struct fields.

Malformed while loop instrad of a for loop (C99 syntax):

```
while (int counter = 0, counter < 560000, counter++) {
```

fp variable is unkown here:

```
while (count < LENGTH && (c = fgetc(fp)) != '\n') {
```

Try to build to write your code progressively and compile it to detect as soon as possible each error. Once the #define is solved each error have their lines indicated, you just have to build, fix the first error, build, fix the second error and so on:

```
In function ‘main’:
101:31: error: incompatible types when assigning to type ‘char[3]’ from type ‘char *’
102:33: error: incompatible types when assigning to type ‘char[30]’ from type ‘char *’
141:27: error: incompatible types when assigning to type ‘char[3]’ from type ‘char *’
142:29: error: incompatible types when assigning to type ‘char[30]’ from type ‘char *’
167:20: error: expected expression before ‘int’
185:49: error: ‘fp’ undeclared (first use in this function)
185:49: note: each undeclared identifier is reported only once for each function it appears in
200:32: error: incompatible types when assigning to type ‘char[30]’ from type ‘char *’
```

After that you have to test your program.

Comment: Thanks, Cidian! I fixed that but still get just as many errors.

Comment: Yes, I am using C99, I think. Added the following in the Codeblocks options:
-std=c99

Comment: Ok indicate it in your question.

Comment: One of the errors says that 'title' is undeclared. However, title was declared. so I don't understand the error.

Comment: Also, there are a number of errors saying "expected ')' before ';' token". After inspecting the lines, I'm not sure where the problem lies.

Comment: Congrats Cidian.. You have found yourself a HELP VAMPIRE

Comment: I don't have this error, check your code why there are these errors. Your fixes seems to be incorrect. The compilator indicates error lines, you just have to see why the variable/token is unknown/missing/incorrect/...
If you have difficulty to fix them,  try to write a new program from scratch (no copy/paste allowed) and compile it after writing each short block to fix each compile error at once.

Comment: Alright, thanks for all the help, Cidian! I'll do that.

Comment: Just realized that I was using a ';' after #define LENGTH 30. Removing the ';' fixed most of the errors.